# How to get the value of Antd Form with React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Below is [TextareaItem](https://mobile.ant.design/components/textarea-item/#components-textarea-item-demo-basic) example of antd-mobile,
I want to rewrite it with React Hooks,
here is my semi-finished code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react"
import { List, TextareaItem } from 'antd-mobile';
import { createForm } from 'rc-form';


function TextareaItemExample {

  useEffect(() => {
    //this.autoFocusInst.focus();
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <List renderHeader={() => 'Customize to focus'}>
        <TextareaItem
          title="title"
          placeholder="auto focus in Alipay client"
          data-seed="logId"
          ref={el => this.autoFocusInst = el}
          autoHeight
        />
        <TextareaItem
          title="content"
          placeholder="click the button below to focus"
          data-seed="logId"
          autoHeight
        />
      </List>
    </div>
  );
}

const TextareaItemExampleWrapper = createForm()(TextareaItemExample);

export default TextareaItemExampleWrapper;
```

**Questions:**
1、How to get the value of `TextareaItem` with React Hooks?I will send ajax requests after getting those values.There is a custom hook [react-use-form-state](https://github.com/wsmd/react-use-form-state) ,but it acts upon html form,how to do the same thing upon Antd Form?

2、How to modify the sentence  `this.autoFocusInst.focus();` in function component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make use of ref you can make use of useRef hook. Also useEffect can be made to behave like `componentDidMount` by providing a second parameter as an empty array. Using a controlled TextAreaItem, you can get the values in state too.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef} from "react"
import { List, TextareaItem } from 'antd-mobile';
import { createForm } from 'rc-form';


function TextareaItemExample {

  const [title, setTitle] = useState();
  const [content, setContent] = useState();

  const handleTitleChange = (value) => {
      setTitle(value);
  }
  const handleContentChange = (value) => {
      setContent(value)
  }
  const autoFocusInt = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    autoFocusInst.current.focus();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <List renderHeader={() => 'Customize to focus'}>
        <TextareaItem
          title="title"
          value={title}
          onChange={handleTitleChange}
          placeholder="auto focus in Alipay client"
          data-seed="logId"
          ref={autoFocusInst}
          autoHeight
        />
        <TextareaItem
          title="content"
          value={content}
          onChange={handleContentChange}
          placeholder="click the button below to focus"
          data-seed="logId"
          autoHeight
        />
      </List>
    </div>
  );
}

const TextareaItemExampleWrapper = createForm()(TextareaItemExample);

export default TextareaItemExampleWrapper;
```

If you don't make it a controlled input, probably you could get the values using ref.